# Is there an easy way for the user to choose which lists/strings can be combined flexibly?

Tags: python, list, input

I have a lot of different categories of lists. I am trying to figure out an efficient way to let a user provide input to tell the script which lists to use for an action.

For instance, I have 20 different lists and a user wants to use 3 of them  to combine to one temporary list, what is the best way to code that?

I am pretty novice at python so my first instinct is to just use a million if-statements, but I doubt that is the most efficient way to do things.

Expected result:

```
list1
list2
list3
list4
list5
```

user somehow says "give me lists 2, 4, and 5.

and a user list is generated that is `List0 = list2 + list4 + list5`

Comment: How do you define your `lists`?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the lists in a dictionary.

```
all_lists = {"list1": list1, "list2": list2, ...}
```

Then the user selects the 3 lists:

```
name1 = input("First list name:")
name2 = input("Second list name:")
name3 = input("Third list name:")
list0 = all_lists[name1] + all_lists[name2] + all_lists[name3]
```

Comment: okay thanks. But if my user only wants 2 lists and not 3, is there no way to build it so it scales nicely with how many lists they want?

Comment: you can put the inputs into a list, and loop over the list to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to split this issue into multiple programming tasks (Divide and conquer), I would worry about user input as the first and concatenation of lists as the second.

The easiest way for the user to specify the lists is to use the input() method. An example below:

```
user_input = input("Please enter the list indexes")
list_indexes = user_input.split(',')
```

Using this code above an example of some user input and the result can be found below:

User input: '1, 4, 5'

```
list_indexes = ['1', '4', '5']
```

Now that we have handled user input, we can use this to concatenate the lists.

We need to be able to access each of the categories with the same reference (If you would like to know why, please let me know and I will explain). One way of doing this is to place all of your category lists into a larger list called 'categories'

```
categories = [list1, list2, list3,...,list(n)]
```

We can then iterate over the categories and pull out the data that we need.

```
concatenated_list = []
for index, category in enumerate(categories):
    if (index in (int(i) for i in list_indexes):
        concatenated_list.extend(category)
```

Comment: wow thanks that was crazy helpful. I have been trying to use the "divide and conquer" strategy myself. It's just rough since I don't know what a lot of different commands do yet. I've never even seen some of those before.

Comment: It's ok, we all started somewhere. Keep at it and they will all make sense soon enough :) Key methods to keep an eye on: enumerate(returns the index and value of elements in a collection), i for i in list (This is called list comprehension(Crazy Useful)), list.extend(much like list.append) =>https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/

Comment: actually i think there may be something wrong with that last block of code. Python is seeing syntactical errors in the if statement

Comment: nevermind. error on my part. 
Only other thing is currently that user_input.split() method, while helpful, is still giving me a list of strings, where I need the categories =[] to contain the actual list variables.

Comment: Categories should not contain the actual list variables, that is what concatenated_list variable is for. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InquirerPy](https://inquirerpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to let the user select the lists

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from InquirerPy import inquirer
from InquirerPy.base.control import Choice

lists = {'list1':[1,2,3], 'list2':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'list3':['something', 'else'], 'list4': []}

def t(result):
    l = []
    for r in result:
        l += lists[r]
    return l

inquirer.select(
            message="Select lists:",
            choices=lists.keys(),
            multiselect=True,
            transformer=t
            ).execute()
```